# Layers Properties - Extent - Custom Extent

Tags: arcgis-desktop, extents

If I were to set up a custom extent on several global data layers using a smaller geographic region (i.e. North America), will Arc still "draw/process" that data even though it is hidden outside my North America boundary?  I'm wondering because I have a lot of global data layers that have symbology and labels but I don't need to view them all the time during my work day (although I do still need them from time to time so I cannot just clip or remove the data from my project).  Do you think my performance would be improved if I use the custom extent and potentially eliminate drawing on the map?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  This question is highly dependent on the data involved.  If all your features cross the International Date Line, then the spatial index will be relatively useless, and performance will be impacted. If there are relatively few large envelope features, then the zoomed data might be performant. The only way to tell with your particular dataset is to benchmark it.

Answer (score 1):

Right click in your data frame, go to Data Frame Properties > Data Frame > Clip Options and select Clip to Shape. You can choose your feature "North America". If you want to focus in on a state or other area in the future you can do so. This has improved performance for me in the past since since it doesn't waste time drawing everything. This maintains your datasets in their original form, so you don't have to clip or remove anything from your data set.